# Nuxt i18n in plugins, error: TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function

Tags: localization, vue-component, middleware, nuxt3, vue-i18n

everyone! I would like to compile my existing project (nuxt3). However, so that the link also changes.

Because of the theme, I can't put what I need in the nuxt.config.ts file. It is in the plugins (see the picture). I've already tried all the basic things and now I'm trying the middleware, but I'm not succeeding.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb1LG.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG2ff.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClpEX.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkJNV.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyS21.png)

I tried: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/ but because of the theme is not useful. I need a completely different solution.